# Remote script execution on Windows 2003 server - alternatives to PSEXEC

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-access

We are wanting to deploy our application to our Test server from our Hudson server.

I'd like to be able to have hudson copy the application files and start a script that would run locally on our Test server.

We can't use psexec because of a cross domain policy.

Currently we are doing this manually, by RDPing to the Test server and checking out the code from subversion manually.

Are there alternatives to PSExec that can bypass the cross domain policy problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write a program to execute stuff using the [CreateProcessWithLogonW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(v=VS.85).aspx) function. You could also try [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) but I have not tried it.

PS: Policies exist to facilitate work, not block it.

Comment: Policies also, and probably mostly, exist for security reasons. I also wouldn't allow remote execution from another domain.

Comment: My point was not abandoning policy. But if a certain need is not satisfied by a policy, a solution (and not a hack offered from 30000 Km away) must be found, even if this causes a policy change / exception. Is it safer and more cost effective for the OP's employer to keep the current state? Or will it be better if an automated solution gets installed which is what he is seeking? For in a way what he is currently doing is a remote execution from another domain, hence a policy violation, only he does so manually. Either he must stop, or the policy must change.